# The relation between the minimal polynomial of $\textbf{A}$ and the monic greatest common divisor of all elements of $adj((s\textbf{I}-\textbf{A}))$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

From the relation of following equation

${(s\textbf{I}-\textbf{A})^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\Delta(s)} \text{adj}((s\textbf{I}-\textbf{A}))$,

the textbook says $\psi(s)=\Delta(s)/m(s)$.

$\Delta(s)$ means $\det(s\textbf{I}-\textbf{A})$,

$\psi(s)$ means the minimal polynomial of $\textbf{A}$,

and $m(s)$ means the monic greatest common divisor of all elements of $\text{adj}((s\textbf{I}-\textbf{A}))$.

But I can't derive the relation above. How to prove $\psi(s)=\Delta(s)/m(s)$?

Comment: This was proved in sec. 29 (pp. 77-79) of [*Vectors and Matrices*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.84459) by MacDuffee (1943).

Comment: If you know the Rational Canonical Form Theorem, and the algorithm to compute Smith Normal Form, then this is an immediate corollary. I think that the reference given by @user1551 proves the result as a step towards RCF.